# Radio antenna isolating transformer

Tags: transformer, transmission-line, transceiver

I need to isolate galvanically my antenna from my RF transceiver. For this I have been recommended a transformer, I select a 1:1 transformer operating in high frequency range. Is it enough to wire it in between the antenna and the transmitter, or we need to take more considerations. The present antenna impedance is 50E.

I also need recommendation for ferrite core to operate at 900MHz and provide least insertion loss.

Comment: Would be useful to know the power required.

Comment: The power is 30dBm max .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try CoilCraft - they have this that is suitable for your operating frequency: -

[image]

I don't think they can handle much power (1/4 watt say [CoilCraft](http://www.coilcraft-cps.com/products/widebands.cfm)). Insertion loss is 0.7dB which is OK but nothing special. I still believe an air-cored transformer is the best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the specs ,yes  most of the manufacturers offer low power . Air core fabrication will take a lot of testing, i'll check if some manufacturer developes aircore transformers.